# Creating a flat lighting Shader in the style of Alphonse Mucha

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, npr, toon-shading

I'm attempting to create a character shader that mimics the artistic style of Alphonse Mucha.

[image]
[image]

The style consists of the skin having a singular base color that's then shaded from the brightest edge to the darkest—but in accordance with how it appears to the camera. So essentially the lighting is shaded purely from the 2D perspective of what the camera sees. To my understanding, to recreate this NPR shader the character models first need to have a flat base color and then shadows have to be added in a separate pass.

I've tried numerous techniques to achieve this approach but all of them have failed in some way. For instance, any attempt at using a normal map ends up in too much shading. I strictly only want shading on the edges to create the effect of 3-dimentional depth. I've attempted to use the XYZ position of a single lightsource to influence a normal map that's then used with a ColorRamp to create a gradient I can use as a shadow, but that too yielded the same problem of too much shading.

Additionally, and most **crucially**, I haven't been able to conceive of a method that allows the shader to also interact with light without ruining the illustrated look. If I use any BDSF shader node to get light interaction, I always find that it ruins the entire look in some way. Perhaps the solution lies in a normal map that has its vector position driven by the coordinates of a light? I'm not sure.

I need to figure out how to design a shader than can do 3 things;

1. Apply a base color to the mesh (no shadows, reflections, anything)
2. Create a 2D gradient shadow map that transitions from lightest to darkest edge, and the angle of the gradient is determined by where the light is coming from. (from the side, up, down, etc)
3. Combine both the shadow map and base color to create a seamless transition from the base color to a darker version.
4. **The shader must react with light. So if the model is in a dark environment, it shouldn't be fully bright like it's in broad daylight.**

My guess is I need to track the angle at which light is pointing towards the mesh, or something to that effect. I've spent a week now trying to figure it out but I just can't.

What I'm currently doing is simply mixing the shadow color and the base color together and using a gradient as the factor in the mixRGB node. (and later applying a paper texture to give it texture)[image]
[image]